# MSSQL query error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to access data from two table in which data is on hourly basis. I am using union query to work on this as given below

```
( SELECT T.unit1,t.CurrentDate,t.CurrentTime,loc,Unit2,value,Description FROM fore T  WHERE   loc=@loc AND CurrentDateTIME =@c0 AND quan='CO'  
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM audit WHERE  startdate<=CAST(@c0dt AS DATE) AND StartTime<=CAST(@c0dt AS TIME) AND (ENDDATE >= CAST(@c0dt AS DATE) OR EndDate IS NULL )
AND (ENDTIME>=CAST(@c0dt AS TIME) OR enDtime IS NULL ) AND loc=@loc AND unit1='CO')

UNION 

SELECT TOP 1 T.unit1,t.CurrentDate,t.CurrentTime,loc,'' as Unit2 ,CAST(VALUE AS SMALLINT) value ,Description FROM  audit T WHERE startdate<=CAST(getdate() AS DATE) 
AND StartTime <= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)AND (enddate>=getdate()  OR ENDDATE IS NOT NULL )   AND (endTime>=CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) OR enDtime IS NULL) 
AND loc=@loc AND unit1='CO')
```

The table I am accessing are given below:

Table audit :

```
id  currentdate     currentdatetime             currenttime     loc     unit1   value   Desc    startdate   startdatetime           starttime   enddate     enddate     enddatetime 
1   2015-08-19      2015-08-19 18:00:06.000     18:00:00        B1      C0      40.0000         2015-08-19  2015-08-19 18:00:00.000 18:00:00    2015-08-18  18:00:00    2015-08-18 18:00:00.000
```

Table Fore :

```
currentdate     currenttime     loc     unit1   unit2   concern     value   description currentdatetime
2015-08-19      15:00:00        B1      C0      m       .1700       5       Good        2015-08-19 15:00:00.000
2015-08-19      16:00:00        B1      C0      m       14.7000     35      Good        2015-08-19 16:00:00.000
2015-08-19      17:00:00        B1      C0      m       6.5600      7       Good        2015-08-19 17:00:00.000
2015-08-19      19:00:00        B1      C0      m       19.6000     20      Good        2015-08-19 19:00:00.000
```

The description of above two tables are as follows the in table : Fore  consist of data from hourly dump, and table : audit consist of user modified date if the data isn't available for that hour user manually enter the data.

I want to write a union which should get the data taking c0dt `@c0dt datetime` which I get from front end. So the issue is when I run above query I do not get data from audit table which is entered manually for that hour.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are getting?

Comment: added the output what i am getting and what i need

Comment: what a meaningful title !

Comment: I see that you have edited your question. How in the world you would get such a result with that query I don't understand. Either you have a different data than the one you have shown here or you are using a different query.

Comment: the data is same and query too is same

Answer (score 1):

Just curious if this works:  I thought I remember reading somewhere that Union with TOP doesn't work well in MSSQL... I'm trying to find the article.  Thought it had something to do with the order by needed for top to work, but order by can only be defined on the union of both data sets... a way around it was to use a CTE or inline views...  Which is why I ask if this CTE example works.

```
WITH A AS ( SELECT 
    T.unit1
    ,t.CurrentDate
    ,t.CurrentTime
    ,loc
    ,Unit2
    ,value
    ,Description 
  FROM fore T  
  WHERE   loc=@loc 
  AND     CurrentDateTIME =@c0 
  AND quan='CO'  
  AND NOT EXISTS(   SELECT 1 
                    FROM audit 
                    WHERE  startdate<=CAST(@c0dt AS DATE) 
                    AND StartTime<=CAST(@c0dt AS TIME) 
                    AND (ENDDATE >= CAST(@c0dt AS DATE) 
                         OR EndDate IS NULL )
                    AND (ENDTIME>=CAST(@c0dt AS TIME) 
                         OR enDtime IS NULL ) 
                    AND loc=@loc 
                    AND unit1='CO'),
B as (SELECT TOP 1 
    T.unit1
    ,t.CurrentDate
    ,t.CurrentTime
    ,loc
    ,'' as Unit2 
    ,CAST(VALUE AS SMALLINT) value 
    ,Description 
  FROM  audit T 
  WHERE startdate<=CAST(getdate() AS DATE) 
  AND StartTime <= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)
  AND (enddate>=getdate()  
       OR ENDDATE IS NOT NULL ) 
  AND (endTime>=CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) 
       OR enDtime IS NULL) 
  AND loc=@loc 
  AND unit1='CO'))
SELECT * from A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B;
```

Answer (score 0):

With these data and query I think you wouldn't get any results. You have an enddate before startdate.

PS: You have a peculiar design redundantly having date, time and datetime fields for the same thing.

Comment: The audit table in this case takes the data from front end application and it saves the date in this format.